# How to fix this code so it uses part of the file name

Tags: python

i need the following code modified so it finds the correct path based on the file name.

the file names vary as follows:

- M_200303HORN_STA.ASC
- M_200604HORN_STA.DAT
- 3D_MR_200303HORN_STA.csv
- 3D_MR_APPROVED_P_SS_2 ().HORNST_3D_MR_200226HORN_STA.csv
- 3D_MR_APPROVED_P_SS_4.LILYN8_3D_MR_210409LILY_RDN.csv
- 3D_MR_APPROVED_P_SS_4.LILYS2_3D_MR_210409LILY_RDS.csv
- 3D_MR_APPROVED_P_SS_6 ().MOOST1_3D_MR_210409MOOR_ST.csv

the common thing is HORN_STA

at the moment its reading only HORN however I need to modify it so it reads HORN_STA as in some cases there going to be files called HORN_STA and HORN_STD

also in some cases the name ending is 2 or 4 letters

the files need to get sorted into these folders as shown below
[folder path example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4CJS.png)

Code:

import os
import shutil
import re
pattern = r'([.*?])'

#!read the name of the directory and files from the current working directory!

```
def read_information():
files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.curdir) if os.path.isfile(f)]
dir = [d for d in os.listdir(os.curdir) if os.path.isdir(d)]
return(files, dir)
```

#!sort the files to the corresponding folder

```
def sorti(name, subfolder, files):
for i in files:
    _new = i.split(".")
    if len(_new) == 2:
        dir = re.split('(\d+)',_new[0])
        if dir[len(dir)-1] in name:
            new_dir = name[dir[len(dir)-1]]
    elif len(_new) ==3:
        dir = re.split('(\d+)',_new[1])
        if dir[len(dir)-1] in name:
            new_dir = name[dir[len(dir)-1]]
    if _new[len(_new)-1].lower() == "csv":
        if "APPROVED" in i:
            sub_dir = subfolder["APPROVED"]
            path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
            path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+sub_dir+"//"+i
            change_folder(path_old, path_new)
        else:
            sub_dir = subfolder["KRONOS"]
            path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
            path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+sub_dir+"//"+i
            change_folder(path_old, path_new)
    elif _new[len(_new)-1].lower() == "db":
            sub_dir = subfolder["DB"]
            path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
            path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+sub_dir+"//"+i
            change_folder(path_old, path_new)
    elif _new[len(_new)-1].lower() == "gsi":
            sub_dir = subfolder["GSI"]
            path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
            path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+sub_dir+"//"+i
            change_folder(path_old, path_new)

        elif _new[len(_new)-1].lower() == "dat" or _new[len(_new)-1].lower() == "asc" or _new[len(_new)-1].lower() == "txt":
            sub_dir = subfolder["DETAILS"]
            path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
            path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+sub_dir+"//"+i
            change_folder(path_old, path_new)

def sort(files, dir):
for i in files:
    tmp = i.split(".") #separate the extension to find the directory name!
    if len(tmp) == 3:
        new_dir = file_name(tmp[1])
    else:
        new_dir = file_name(tmp[0])
    #print(tmp, new_dir)
    if tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "csv" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "CSV":
        if "APPROVED" in i:
            path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
            path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+FOLDER1+"//"+i
            change_folder(path_old, path_new)
        else: 
            path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
            path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+FOLDER2+"//"+i
            change_folder(path_old, path_new)  
    elif tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "DB" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "db" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "GSI" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "gsi" :
        path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
        path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+FOLDER3+"//"+i
        change_folder(path_old, path_new)
    elif tmp[len(tmp)-1].lower() == "DAT" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "dat" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "ASC" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "asc" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "TXT" or tmp[len(tmp)-1] == "txt":
        path_old = os.curdir+"//"+i
        path_new = os.curdir+"//"+new_dir+"//"+FOLDER4+"//"+i
        change_folder(path_old, path_new)
```

## check the folder name

```
def file_info(files, directory):
_tmp = []
for i in files:
    _new = i.split(".") #separate the extension to find the directory name!
    if len(_new) == 2:
        dir = re.split('(\d+)',_new[0])
        if dir[len(dir)-1] not in _tmp:
            _tmp.append(dir[len(dir)-1])
    elif len(_new) ==3:
        dir = re.split('(\d+)',_new[1])
        if dir[len(dir)-1] not in _tmp:
            _tmp.append(dir[len(dir)-1])
_tmp_dir = {}
for i in _tmp:    
    _t = i.lower().split("_")
    for j in directory:
        _u = j.lower().split("_")
        for k in _u:
            if k in _t[0]:
                _tmp_dir[i] = j
                break
return (_tmp_dir)  

def associate_dir_name(directory, set):
_tmp = {}
for i in directory:
    for j in set:
        #print(i,j)
        _t = (re.findall(str(j),str(i))) 
        if _t:
            _tmp[j] = i 
return(_tmp) 

def change_folder(path_old, path_new):
#print(path_new)
try:
    shutil.move(path_old, path_new) #move to the new path! 
except: 
    pass
return

def check_sub_folder(path):
_tmp = {}
path_name = "./"+path+"/"
dir = [d.name for d in os.scandir(path_name) if os.path.isdir(d)]
for i in dir:
    tmp = i.lower()
    j = tmp.split(' ')
    if "approved" in j:
        _tmp["APPROVED"] = i
    elif "kronos" in tmp:
        _tmp["KRONOS"] = i
    elif "details" in tmp:
        _tmp["DETAILS"] = i
    elif "raw" in tmp:
        if "gsi" in tmp:
            _tmp["GSI"] = i
        else:
            _tmp["DB"] = i
return _tmp            

if __name__ == "__main__":
files, directory = read_information()
name = file_info(files, directory)
for path in directory:
    sub_def = check_sub_folder(path)
    #print(sub_def)
    sorti(name, sub_def, files)
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to expect people to read through. I would suggest using a `Path` from `pathlib` and some simple `glob` values to get specific files for each "bucket" -- e.g. `my_path.glob("*HORN_ST*.*")` would get you everything you need to put into the Hornsey St directory. That's not a really specific glob, so you can make that as granular as you want. The idea is to use `glob` as an iterator rather than reinvent the wheel.